# GET http://localhost/v5/api/checker 404 (Not Found) Slim

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, slim

I'm trying to do a function with call AJAX to php but when I click the button it shows this error, some one knows how can I solve it? My code below.

PHP:

```
$app->get('/checker', function () {
    $jsonContents = file_get_contents('data/data.json');
    $data= json_decode($jsonContents,  true);
    foreach ($data as $key =>[$value]) {
        $host = $value['domain'];
        exec('ping -c 2' . $host,$output,$result);
        ECHO $result;
    }
});
```

JS AJAX:

```
function CallChecker() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api/checker',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: 404 means that the URL couldn't resolve. You sure your app is listening on `localhost/v5/api`?

Comment: Yeah, the others buttons are working

Comment: I think you're making ajax request to an invalid url. In your PHP code you're defining a `/checker` route, in your JavaScript code you're making a request to `api/checker` and in your question title you're mentioning `/v5/api/checker`.

Comment: I'm calling api/checker because the php file is located on api folder

Comment: By PHP file you mean your application's index.php? Where is your index.php located relative to your web server's document root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have strong doubts that Slim router follows your directories path. 
I don't know your complete configuration, so I may be mistaken, but try to access *http://localhost/checker* or *http://localhost/v5/checker* and see if it shows you something.

Also in javascript you set URL as relative, which may work only if you call it from the home page. Instead you should add slash like this:

```
url: '/api/checker',
```

But again - try *'/checker'* or *'/v5/checker'*, I believe it's the way how most routers should work.